# Using formulas with german format in Excel?

Tags: excel, formula, cell-formatting

I use formulas in excel, and I have noticed a weird behavior using a German cell format.

1. In excel, select A1 an set its format to: (regional) German, Versicherungsnachweis-Nr.
2. Type "=SUM(B1:B3)" in A1. I used SUM in this example but the result is the same for anything starting with "=".

The behavior I get is that A1 is shown as a string. The format adds "[ ]", so the cell is read as "[=SUM(B1:B3)]", even though the content really starts with "=".

[image: See here a screenshot.]

I have found absolutely nothing related to this on the internet, how can I have Excel to recognize the cell as a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Versicherungsnachweis-Nr.` format is translated to this:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "\[@\]"
```

which forces the formula inside to act as a string. Thus, the formula is not evaluated. If you want it to be evaluated, change the format to general, and concatenate the two `[` and `]`:

```
="["&SUMME(C1:C3)&"]"
```

---

`=SUM()` in German is `=SUMME()`. See this for a reference of all German formulas:

http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/excel/index.php?langids=en+de

Comment: I've tried it as well, and with other languages too. The behavior stays the same, that's why I used SUM.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think about checking the number format. Thanks.